# Resetting password using PHP for mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have been following this guide on learning how to create a PHP script that is able to register users by taking in the required fields like `username`, `password`. This script uses a SALT value to encrypt the password.

I am fairly new PHP, how would it be possible to create another script that would also allow a user to RESET the password created in this registration.

```
<?php

//importing required script
require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!verifyRequiredParams(array('username', 'password'))) {
        //getting values
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //creating db operation object
        $db = new DbOperation();

        //adding user to database
        $result = $db->createUser($username, $password);

        //making the response accordingly
        if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = 'User created successfully';
        } elseif ($result == USER_ALREADY_EXIST) {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'User already exist';
        } elseif ($result == USER_NOT_CREATED) {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Some error occurred';
        }
    } else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Required parameters are missing';
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid request';
}

//function to validate the required parameter in request
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields)
{

    //Getting the request parameters
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;

    //Looping through all the parameters
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        //if any requred parameter is missing
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {

            //returning true;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: I can not see the Function `createUser`. Basically you need make 1 new function: `updateUserPass` and replace it with `createUser`. On mysql side you need to `UPDATE` user instead of `INSERT` new user. You will also need to create a HTML form which submits (POSTS) the New Password + user data to update.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://www.allphptricks.com/forgot-password-recovery-reset-using-php-and-mysql/

Basically, you need to create another table within the database which, when a user clicks forgot password generates a key and will temporarily store it in the database and then will send a link to there email where they can reset it.

If you need any help getting it working, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

if you beginner then learns the basics of PHP.

Well if you want to add the RESET password created in this registration. So You will have to create a field named token in the database and generate a token in this field with the help of PHP, we will send the reset link to this token, then we will pass the $token variable in this link, through which the user can set his new password.

could. To know more you can read its article - https://www.rkonline.in/2022/11/forgot-password-reset-using-php-and-mysql.html